# scrollView.scrollTo() speed control?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

I would like to programmatically scroll to a specific point in a
scrollView...which I can do just fine...
Except I land there instantly.

Is there a way to control the speed of the scroll so it looks smoother?

Could somebody point me to an animation with a scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use object animator to scroll:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY",  scrollTo).setDuration(duration).start();
```

or you can use ContDownTimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(2000, 20) { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
            scrollView.scrollTo((int) (2000 - millisUntilFinished), 0); 
        } 

        public void onFinish() { 

        } 
     }.start();
```

Comment: i use this.it automatically scroll itself.but i need when user scroll it smooth.how can i do it?

Comment: i try both.but,scroll not smooth.it scroll fast.how to slow on when user scroll???

Comment: You can override onScroll method of scrollview to controll speed

Answer (score 0):

There is method for that if you want to scroll it smoothly `smoothScrollTo()`

use it Like

`scrollView.smoothScrollTo(xPos, yPos);`

Comment: i also try this.this is not working.still scroll fast...not smooth & slow on while scrolling...